# Why is the open ball in a discrete space with radius 2 the metric space itself?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the definition of open ball as following(dealing with metric space $(M, d)$):

Given $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, the set $B_r(x) = \{ y \in M : d(x,y) < r\}$ is called the open ball about $x$ of radius $r$.

Then it says that in a discrete space $B_1(x) = \{x\}$ and $B_2(x) = M$.

I don't understand why $B_2(x) = M$...

Thank you!

reference: Real Analysis by N.L.Carothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a discrete metric space M, $d(x,y)=1$ for all $y \neq x$. So, $B_2(x)=M$ as $d(x,y)=1 < 2$ for all $y \neq x$ and $d(x,x)=0$ anyway.

Comment: More precisely, the claim holds for a *space with the discrete metric*, but may be wrong for a *discrete metric space*. E.g. $\mathbb Z$ with the usual metric is discrete, but thta is not the discrete (i.e. zero-one) metric.

Comment: Yes @HagenvonEitzen: That's the correct "wording". Thanks.