# Open balls with $r > 1$ in real space with discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've read a question

> [Why is the open ball in a discrete space with radius 2 the metric
>   space itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652926/why-is-the-open-ball-in-a-discrete-space-with-radius-2-the-metric-space-itself)

where the answer to my question was given

> In a discrete metric space $M$, $d(x,y)=1$ for all $y\neq x$. So, $B_2(x)=M$ as $d(x,y)=1<2$ for all $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$ anyway.
>   But I'm still not getting the details.

The ball in metric spaces can be $B(x, r) = \lbrace x\rbrace$ for $r \leq 1$ or $B(x, r) = X$ for $r > 1$. I'm getting why the ball with $r < 1$ is just a point - there can be a distance $0$ (in case that $x = y$, which is not our case, because $r > 0$) or $1$ (in that case $y\notin B(x, r)$) in discrete metric.

But, for the case $r > 1$, I still can't get why the ball is a whole set $X$. Can somebody, please, explain it in more details than in the question above?

Thanks.

Comment: Write down the definition of $B(x,r)$. If you look at the definition, you should see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Are two points ever farther away than 1 unit from each other in the discrete metric?

Comment: No, the points are always 1 unit distant.

Comment: You're on the right track. Draw a picture and/or look at the definition of $B(x,r)$, as suggested by @Daniel Fischer♦

Comment: $B(x, r) = \left\lbrace y \in X|d_0(x, y) < r\right\rbrace$. If we take, for example, $r = 2$ from the question before, for $x\neq y$ the definition will be $d_0(x, y) = 1 < 2$ (as seen before), which is always true. So, is that implying that for $r > 1$ the statement is valid for all points in some set $X$, let's say?

Comment: Correct. No need to say "some set $X$," as $X$ is the given space on which you equip the discrete metric.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦, par, thank you gentlemans!